# Provide own file-based dictionary via link to ChatGPT for NER

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4

Is it possible to provide my own file-based dictionary containing IDs, names, and aliases to ChatGPT via the API? For example I'll provide a link to CSV file from Google Drive to ChatGPT. This is intended to enable me to ask ChatGPT to perform Named Entity Recognition (NER) on various texts using the provided dictionary. If this is possible, could you please show me which API methods I should use to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Asking for recommendations might not be appropriate on the Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but it might be possible to ask the question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Also, logging it on https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76949597